# ROS fuerte rosmake -std=c++11 compile error

Tags: ros, rosmake, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was trying to compile a node that uses a library that needs c++11 flag (It uses std::function and nullptr among other features).

Here is de outpulog:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mr8gltnrdn162xi/build_output.log?dl=0

But summarizing:

```
               from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:62,
               from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62,
               from /usr/include/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:16,
               from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:13,
               from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/time.h:58,
               from /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/ros.h:38,
               from /home/bardo91/programming/EC-SAFEMOBIL/ros/PatrollingCV/uav_vision/src/uav_vision_node.cpp:9:
     /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >; _Args = {actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >&}]’:
       /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; _ForwardIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’

     /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:117:41:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; _ForwardIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*]’
      /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:258:63:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; _ForwardIterator = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >*; _Tp = actionlib_msgs::GoalStatus_<std::allocator<void> >]’
```

And so on... It's not only for the library, I would like to use new features of c++, but I don't know what to do to fix it.
Can anybody help me?

Thank in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203396/ros-fuerte-rosmake--std=c++11-compile-error/) by [Bardo91](https://answers.ros.org/users/12326/bardo91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS fuerte do not use all about c++11. Moving to ROS indigo fix the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Bardo91](https://answers.ros.org/users/12326/bardo91/) with karma: 30 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0